# Android Studio - Webpage Link from TextView

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

I am able to link my Textview to a web page.
But, when I use this feature, an external web page is opened and the connection between the webpage and the app is lost.
Is there a way to display the webpage inside my app?

Comment: Can you show us some code how you have linked the webpage so that we can give a proper solution to your problem

Comment: Spanned html1 = Html.fromHtml( "<a href='https://www.google.com/'>Google.com</a>");
                TextView6.setText(html1);

Answer (score 0):

**Solution1**

Create a separate activity and have a Webview in it and onclick of the TextView move to that activity.

**Solution2**

Use Chrome CustomTabs and onclick of the Textview open the CustomTabsIntent